# as3 How to dispatch a specific keyboard event

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I was [looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=as3%20dispatch%20a%20keyboard%20event) this answer and had no luck. [One place I looked](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/599645) actually had a very discouraging answer: "You cannot force mouse or keyboard events - they HAVE TO come from mouse or keyboard."

Huh?

I tried 'brute force' and came up with this solution. Maybe I'm going about it wrongly or stupidly; is there a better way?

I had a keyboard event that launched a class and wanted to put a sprite on the stage that would initiate this same action -- clicking on the sprite would launch the keyboard event (Escape key).

In the eventListener function, I `traced` the event **e** itself:

```
    private function keys(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
        trace("EscapeKey: ",e);   
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        ...    
        }
    }
```

The output was

```
EscapeKey: [KeyboardEvent type="keyDown" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 charCode=27 keyCode=27 keyLocation=0 ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false]
```

I then had the mouseClick listener create and dispatch a new keyboardEvent using the values I got from the above trace:

```
    private function pauseClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var a:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keyDown", true, false, 27, 27, 0, false, false, false);
        stage.dispatchEvent(a);
    }
```

Presto!
Hopefully, this post will come in handy to others looking for these types of mouse/keyboard event redundancies.

**EDIT**   ---  A complete class example requested in comments:

```
package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class KeyboardMouse extends Sprite {
        private var pauseInfo:PauseInfo;

        private var escapeKey:EscapeKey;

        public function KeyboardMouse() {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keys);

            escapeKey = new EscapeKey();
            stage.addChild(escapeKey);

            pauseInfo = new PauseInfo();
            pauseInfo.x = stage.stageWidth;
            pauseInfo.y = stage.stageHeight;
            pauseInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseClick);
            addChild(pauseInfo);
        }

        private function keys(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            trace("KeyboardEvent ",e);
            if (e.keyCode == 27) {  // esc key
                if (stage.contains(escapeKey)){
                    trace("remove escape");
                    escapeKey.visible = false;
                }
                else {
                    trace("show escape");
                    escapeKey.visible = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private function pauseClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        //  The trace in 'keys' gives this:
        //[KeyboardEvent type="keyDown" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 charCode=27 keyCode=27 keyLocation=0 ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false]      

            var a:KeyboardEvent = new KeyboardEvent("keyDown", true, false, 27, 27, 0, false, false, false);
            stage.dispatchEvent(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, and slightly incomprehensible. Would you mind showing a short, simple but complete program demonstrating this 'redundancy'?

Comment: Interesting! I have always just used a common function like `pause()` and then I'd have multiple eventlisteners call that function. That seems easier to me whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @Craig I think this would be like if you want the game to pause (for instance) when the player clicks the pause button but also when the mouse rolls off the window and also when the player presses the P key. That requires 3 different event listeners. So the OP has his key press one working and has figured out a way to call that same event from within another event listener. I think it is much simpler just to have all the eventlisteners just call the same function pause();

Comment: @NealDavis Is this the answer to my question, *"Maybe I'm going about it wrongly or stupidly; is there a better way?"*
Or are there conceivable advantages to handling MouseEvents and KeyboardEvents separately?

Comment: It's a good question. "Better" is subjective here I think. I'd say what is better here is what makes most sense to the one writing the code. It seems more conventional to do it the way I've described but I'm not sure there is a reason for that convention. There are lots of other scenarios in which we want to have many different pieces of code all call the same function, right? Why should this be different? What you're doing is forcing an event that isn't actually happening. Quite interesting and kudos for figuring that out.

Comment: see my answer below. It was too long to fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 and big props to @Neal Davis for his comments!

As he suggests, having *one* listener for both events with an argument of (e:Event) is a cleaner, less convoluted way of achieving the same result:

```
   pauseInfo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,keys);
   stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keys);

   private function keys(e:Event):void {
        trace("EscapeKey: ",e);   
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        ...    
        }
   }
```

Both listeners must still be removed at some point, though, even though only one Listener Function is handling both, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now I get this. I just don’t get it’s purpose. Also there is, I think, an annoying error in the code.

First: you’ve shown that you can essentially ‘cast’ one type of event (e.g. MouseEvent) as another (KeyboardEvent). But you still have a listener function registered for each Event type (which, at some point, you’ll have to remove for memory management purposes) and a newly dispatched Event, so you’re not exactly minimizing code. What, exactly, is the value of this trick? Why not just register a single listener function with multiple event types? Within that function you can discriminate between the Event types and do stuff accordingly, for instance with a line like this:

```
     if(e.type == 'keyDown' || e.type == 'click')
```

Second: you say: **if (stage.contains(escapeKey))** and then you try to make the ‘visible’ property of escapeKey dependent on that. But by making the **escapeKey.visible  =  false** you’re not changing the fact that the stage still contains escapeKey. So the escapeKey will never become visible again because the 'else' condition doesn't exist. I believe that you want to say “**removeChild(escapeKey)**” and then “**addChild(escapeKey)**” instead of setting “**escapeKey.visible  =  false**”    and then “**escapeKey.visible  =  true**”. Then you’re little program does what I think you want it to.

Comment: The "visibility" was just a (bad) example of doing stuff when escape was pressed. I could've just written "..." or "//do something here."
The reason I came up with this solution **at all** is because I couldn't find how to simulate a key press. I was under the impression that a MouseEvent should be handled with an argument of e:MouseEvent, and a KeyboardEvent handled with e:KeyboardEvent. Handling both events with e:Event in one function is the answer to my *actual* question: "is there a better way?"